# Adding the category for a custom entity reference field add other fields to the same category

Tags: 8, entities

I have a custom entity reference field working well, but once I added the category to it the other entity reference fields appeared in the same category.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'region_token' field type.
 *
 * @FieldType(
 *   id = "region_token",
 *   label = @Translation("Region Token"),
 *   description = @Translation("Region custom token."),
 *   category = @Translation("Tokens"),
 *   default_widget = "region_select_widget",
 *   default_formatter = "region_formatter",
 * )
 */
class RegionToken extends EntityReferenceItem {
```

Any idea about how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding the following code to the class

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getPreconfiguredOptions() {
    return [];
  }
```